# Heroku Postgres is not connecting

Tags: java, postgresql, heroku

I have a working app on Heroku with which I can't manage to connect to the database allocated on Heroku

The method that gets the connection:

```
public static Connection connect() {
    Connection conn = null;
    try {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(System.getenv("JDBC_DATABASE_URL"));
        System.out.println("Connected to the PostgreSQL server successfully.");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

    return conn; 
}
```

I check it with this other method on my API Rest:

```
@Path("/db")
@GET
public Response dbWorks() {
    Connection conn = DBManager.connect();
    
    if(conn != null) {
        return Response.status(200).entity(conn).build();
    }
    return Response.status(400).entity(conn).build();
}
```

I does not work even if I write myself jdbc:postgresql://host:port/databasename with all the data that Heroku gives me.

Comment: What do you see in the console for your Heroku dyno? The error message there may help you troubleshoot this.

Comment: Why are you using `JDBC_DATABASE_URL` instead of just `DATABASE_URL`?

Comment: "I does not work even if I write myself jdbc:postgresql://host:port/databasename with all the data that heroku gives me"—what does "does not work" mean? Please read [ask].